# Meaning of not-so-dumb

Tags: meaning

> Style is the external expression of your most internal self. How’s that for some not-so-dumb blonde shit?

I would like some help to understand the meaning of the question above: "How's that for some not-so-dumb blonde shit?"

I know it is a joke, but I can't understand it...

Comment: The opposite of not-so-smart. Please cite the author and give us the link.

Answer (score 2):

*Style is the external expression of your most internal self. How’s that for some not-so-dumb blonde shit?*

- How's that for AKA How about that: a verbal deictic response to an interlocutor regarding some statement or situation in a conversation. Here, it refers to the statement in the first sentence directed at an unknown audience but one who is expected to understand sarcasm.
- dumb blonde: an "antiquated" cliché that blond women are dumb
- not-so-dumb: here, intelligent, bright
- shit: what is said, written or uttered. Here, the first sentence.

Translation into non-comedic terms: What about that thought (the first sentence) woman like me who some would consider stupid because she has blond hair.

The sentence is supposed to be sarcastic pay-back to some unseen adversary.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom has two related meanings.  First is the literal meaning:  The individual is simply not as dumb (stupid) as they may seem.  A less literal meaning is that the individual has insight and intelligence which they somehow conceal.

Comment: And of course _dumb blonde_ is an old-fashioned stereotype of the glamorous but dimwitted woman.

Answer (score 0):

**How’s** = How do you find; What is your opinion of

**that** = what I have just shown you/said/done, etc.

**for** = in the case of. (contextually = when you consider [that it was said/done, etc., by])

**some** = a random example of

**not-so-dumb** - this is an example of [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes#Examples) in which two negatives (not + dumb) combine to provide an emphatic positive effect. (So = to the extent that you might have imagined.)

**blonde** = stereotypically blonde women as supposed to be stupid.

**shit**? = <s>a worthless person</s> clever expression - it refers to the complexity and apparent wisdom of the sentence *"Style is the external expression of your most internal self."* that the speaker has just spoken.

Comment: "shit" in this case is probably "stuff/something I just did"

Comment: You are right. It will refer to the complexity of "Style is the external expression of your most internal self."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the clarifications in other answers, I would argue that there ought also to be a hyphen between "dumb" and "blonde." If one built the sentence up from the minimum, the steps might be:

> How's that for some shit?

At this point the sentence is fairly meaningless, but equates to "What do you make of this stuff?"

Note, the next word to add cannot be "blonde" on its own; "blonde shit" makes no phrasal sense here. Rather...

> How's that for some dumb-blonde shit?

"Dumb blonde" is here being used as a single phrasal modifier of "shit." Opinions may vary about whether hyphens *must* be used, but they certainly help the reader understand clearly, and prevent a reading that interprets the words as "shit that is dumb and also blonde."

In the next step, negation, the author reached for hyphens, "not-so-dumb," but stopped short of adding one more hyphen. If the sentence were "I am a not-so-dumb blonde," this would make sense, since no one would hyphenate "I am a dumb blonde." But by passing up the third hyphen, they create an initial reading of "[not-so-dumb] [blonde shit]," or "blonde shit that is not so dumb."

Comment: So, not-so-learned-aphorism-speak.